# WPF - How to get dynamically added Menu Item Mnemonics to work

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I am dynamically creating a submenu, but I'm finding that the `_` menu item mnemonics are not working firing the menu command. The items show the underlines when the menu is opened with `alt` menu navigation (ie. this is under my Window menu):

```
var mi = Model.Window.MainMenuWindow;               
mi.Items.Clear();

mi.Items.Add(new MenuItem { Header = "_Close Document", Command=Model.Commands.CloseActiveDocumentCommand   });
mi.Items.Add(new MenuItem { Header = "C_lose All Documents", Command=Model.Commands.CloseAllDocumentsCommand, CommandParameter = "All" });
mi.Items.Add(new MenuItem { Header = "Close All _But This Document", Command = Model.Commands.CloseAllDocumentsCommand, CommandParameter="AllBut" });

var menuItems = Model.Window.GenerateContextMenuItemsFromOpenTabs();
if (menuItems.Count < 1)
    return;

mi.Items.Add(new Separator());
foreach (var menu in menuItems)
{

    mi.Items.Add(menu);
}

mi.IsSubmenuOpen = true;
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

The mnemonics propery display the shortcuts, however the hotkeys don't work to fire the associated commands.

Is there something special that needs to happen to the menu when the items are added dynamically to make the shortcut links work?

FWIW, I'm using MahApps.Metro but I suspect that's not really related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the focus on the menu will fix this issue.

```
void ShowActiveTabsList()
{
    WindowMenuCommand = new CommandBase((parameter, command) =>
    {
        var mi = Model.Window.MainMenuWindow;
        mi.Items.Clear();

        mi.Items.Add(new MenuItem { Header = "_Close Document", Command= Model.Commands.CloseActiveDocumentCommand  });
        mi.Items.Add(new MenuItem { Header = "Close _All Documents", Command = Model.Commands.CloseAllDocumentsCommand });
        mi.Items.Add(new MenuItem { Header = "Close All _But This Document", Command = Model.Commands.CloseAllDocumentsCommand, CommandParameter="AllBut" });

        var menuItems = Model.Window.GenerateContextMenuItemsFromOpenTabs();
        if (menuItems.Count < 1)
            return;

        mi.Items.Add(new Separator());
        foreach (var menu in menuItems)
        {

            mi.Items.Add(menu);
        }

        mi.IsSubmenuOpen = true;
        // focus the menu to enable the mnemonics for the dynamically created submenus
        mi.Focus();

        mi.SubmenuClosed += (s,e) => ((MenuItem)s).Items.Clear();
    }, (p, c) => true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jan. Easy fix - shoulda thought of that :-)